# Libreoffice is Frequently Crashing

Tags: 16.04, libreoffice, crash

I'm experiencing Libreoffice frequently crashing without giving any report on what cause it and without communicating failure conditions.

Ordinarily only Libreoffice crash, but sometimes Ubuntu crash too.

I have already reinstalled LibO from Ubuntu repository without any success.

My system details are:

- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
- Libreoffice Version: 5.1.6.2

Comment: Can you give details on size of sheets, macros, formatting, etc?

Comment: I have 10 sheets, with simple formulas, automatic formatting of cells, and one sheet with almost 20 big cells, with 10 lines each. I have graphics too. It's not a huge file, but it is a little bit worked out.  It has 132 kB of size.

Comment: Same problem here, same system details.
(Version: 5.1.6.2; Build ID: 1:5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial2; CPU Threads: 8; OS Version: Linux 4.10; UI Render: default; Locale: en-US (en_US.UTF-8))

I want to add that this happens even with very small, simple writer files (2 pages of text). Furthermore, I've experienced that if LibreOffice has crashed once during a work session, I can be pretty certain it'll crash again within the next half hour. Usually Ubuntu 16.04 LTS fully crashes and work progress in other applications is lost, so I regard this to be a serious problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug was identified.

It was related to Oracle Java, crashing in LibreOffice.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bug/1698391

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1699772

After removing Oracle Java and reinstalling OpenJDK, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

I use kubuntu 17.10. When LO was upgraded to 5.4.5.1 (1:5.4.5-0ubuntu.17.10.1) LO crashed on saving any file, existing on new, any file format. In this case the solution was to remove (I used 'completely remove') the package 'libreoffice-kde' (was version 1:5.4.5-ubuntu0.17.10.1).

Comment: I have the same problem on Kubuntu 17.10. Upgraded to 5.4.5.1 this morning and I can't save any document. Removing the entire KDE integration seems like the nuclear option, anyone has an idea of what might be causing this bug?